# how to update a table using like operator

Tags: mysql

hey i have two table A & B. A consist of student_name  and student_id.  Problem is that i have another table of B which contains student names and student_id . currently B table id field is empty now . Al most all names in A is same as that of B. I used like concat operator for matching. Eg in A 'john samuel Abraham ' is there and 'john samuel A' on B. i want use his id in B table.

```
  SELECT * FROM table2 B  JOIN  table1 A ON A.student_name LIKE CONCAT('%', B.student_name ,'%')
```

from this i can select almost all possible similar names. but names which misspelled can't be selected. why? 
While updating this i can't update entire rows also
my update query is

```
   update table2 B JOIN table1 A ON A.student_name LIKE CONCAT('%', B.student_name ,'%') set B.student_id = A.student_id
```

Comment: You cannot garantee that LIKE will return only one row per ID, so final result will be pretty incorrect. Try to update table B without LIKE and then to match missing IDs and names.

Comment: still 150 records are un affected due to some spelling mistakes .

Comment: i can't enter 150 rows manually